# Instagram: Could I get latest posts of MY account (client id and secret) with no access token?

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

Is the following possible?
As I read on instagram API, each data fetching needs an access token. 
I need to build a vBulletin forum addon where when an instagram user is posting something on his channel, that message is being posted also on his forum board (where he is admin).

The issue is that we're talking a forum / vbulletin side action, not at instagram and my client needs it automatically, so no accept / verification pages more than one times and redirects.

The main thing is that: the account which have the Client on instagram (key / secret) is the same with the account which its posts will be posted too on the external software (vBulletin Forum).

Is there any way to achieve it? And basically: any way generate an access token with no needed any verify action by the account, from the time client key / secret is the same with the account we're talking via PHP to fetching its data?

Comment: There's no way to pull data via the API without an access token, I wouldn't bother developing a vBulletin specific add-in to do this though - assuming their self-hosted and on vBulletin 5 I'd just add a PHP module to the page.